# Disallow .preventDefault() everywhere

Tags: javascript, dom-events, userscripts, preventdefault

I'm trying to write a userscript to block all `.preventDeault()` calls globally for keyboard events and use my own hotkeys instead of being forced to use those defined by different websites. The problem is I can't figure out how one can unbind something like that without looking into a concrete website's code. I don't want to block all JS - just the things that should be in my control instead of developers' - but I don't understand how to make it simple and global.

Comment: You could try to change `Event.prototype.preventDefault`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the ability to prevent default in a website's code is likely to make that site unstable and possibly unusable.

You could create an override of `preventDefault` on `KeyboardEvent` (which is a subclass of `UIEvent`, which is a subclasss of `Event` where the standard `preventDefault` is implemented), like this:

```
KeyboardEvent.prototype.preventDefault = function() { };
```

(The `writable`, `enumerable`, and `configurable` flags on `Event`'s `preventDefault` are all `true`, so no need for `Object.defineProperty` here.)

Example:

```js
KeyboardEvent.prototype.preventDefault = function() { };

// This event handler *should* prevent typing in the input, but doesn't because we've broken preventDefault
document.getElementById("the-input").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="the-input" type="text">
```

Compare that to the version that doesn't override `preventDefault`:

```js
// This event handler prevents typing in the input, because we haven't broken preventDefault
document.getElementById("the-input").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="the-input" type="text">
```

That may work, at least for a subset of modern browsers, but again, I'd strongly recommend against it.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thank you. Btw, most of websites are unusable for me now because of many developers preventing what they shouldn't prevent, for useless effects and features. As a powerful user with powerful browser with vim-like hotkeys, I think, redefining websites' own hotkeys is just a rudeness, because it forces users to adapt to whatever developers had in mind instead of using what users have in browser. It's like every website thinks of itself as it is my whole world.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable `preventDefault` method on `MouseEvent`

```
MouseEvent.prototype.preventDefault = function() { };
```